# how do i catch " The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint"?

Tags: c#

some one show me how to catch that exception please!!

Comment: You need to post the code you are using to call the database. We do not have Cristal balls here.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give an alternative view-point, I *wouldn't* try to catch it. If I am *expecting* this scenario, I would simply check for foreign-key data *before* I try to delete. This avoids complications, especially if that `DELETE` isn't the first thing that happens in the unit of work. And in the case where you have multiple foreign keys, a string-based message isn't very helpful to your code.

I would keep the foreign key, of course - as a sanity check / fallback for the edge cases (for example, concurrency).

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that just a variety of SQLException?

You can find that in System.Data.SqlClient.

```
try
{
     //code
}
catch(SqlException sqlException)
{
    //code
}
```

Updated:  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: If he wants to catch/check for that specific error though, he'll have to inspect `sqlException.Number` and check for the SQL Server error number for this specific error (I'm having a bit trouble finding exactly which number that maps to the error given here though).